# Android: passing member to method of another class as reference?

Tags: android, parameters, reference

I want to pass an argument (Bundle object) to a method of an object of another class, where it gets "copied" to the object. Since it's going be a pretty big Bundle, is there a specific way of copying just a reference to the original object? Does it have anything to do with access speficiers (i.e, a private object always gets copied)? What would be a right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object in Java, you are passing a reference to the object on the heap, so it doesn't create a second copy of the object - just a second reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does the same happen if the member passed (to a method of another class) is private?

Comment: Yep, makes no difference.  All object reference passing works the same way.